# Make Frequency Histogram for Factor Variables

Tags: r, histogram, categorical-data

I am very new to R, so I apologize for such a basic question. I spent an hour googling this issue, but couldn't find a solution.

Say I have some categorical data in my data set about common pet types. I input it as a character vector in R that contains the names of different types of animals. I created it like this:

```
animals <- c("cat", "dog",  "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "bird")
```

I turn it into a factor for use with other vectors in my data frame:

```
animalFactor <- as.factor(animals)
```

I now want to create a histogram that shows the frequency of each variable on the y-axis, the name of each factor on the x-axis, and contains one bar for each factor. I attempt this code:

```
hist(table(animalFactor), freq=TRUE, xlab = levels(animalFactor), ylab = "Frequencies")
```

The output is absolutely nothing like I'd expect. Labeling problems aside, I can't seem to figure out how to create a simple frequency histogram by category.

Comment: Histograms are for continuous data. You want a bar chart.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

It seems like you want `barplot(prop.table(table(animals)))`:

[image]

However, this is not a histogram.

Comment: If you just do `barplot(table(animals))` you get this more like a histogram, i.e. as counts without normalization.

Answer (score 33):

If you'd like to do this in `ggplot`, an API change was made to `geom_histogram()` that leads to an error: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/1465

To get around this, use `geom_bar()`:

```
animals <- c("cat", "dog",  "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "cat", "bird")

library(ggplot2)
# counts
ggplot(data.frame(animals), aes(x=animals)) +
  geom_bar()
```

[image]

Comment: geom_bar() is for cualitative (categorical) variables and geom_histogram() for cuantitative variables.

Answer (score 15):

The reason you are getting the unexpected result is that `hist(...)` calculates the distribution from a numeric vector. In your code, `table(animalFactor)` behaves like a numeric vector with three elements: 1, 3, 7. So `hist(...)` plots the number of 1's (1), the number of 3's (1), and the number of 7's (1). @Roland's solution is the simplest.

Here's a way to do this using `ggplot`:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggp <- ggplot(data.frame(animals),aes(x=animals))
# counts
ggp + geom_histogram(fill="lightgreen")
# proportion
ggp + geom_histogram(fill="lightblue",aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)))
```

[image]

You would get precisely the  same result using `animalFactor` instead of `animals` in the code above.

Comment: See [megatron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37622400/4895725) for newer versions of `ggplot2`.

Comment: geom_bar() is for cualitative (categorical) variables and geom_histogram() for cuantitative variables.

Answer (score 4):

Country is a categorical variable and I want to see how many occurences of country exist in the data set. In other words, how many records/attendees are from each Country

```
barplot(summary(df$Country))
```

Answer (score 2):

Data as factor can be used as input to the plot function.

An answer to a similar question has been given here:
https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-December/261873.html

```
 x=sample(c("Richard", "Minnie", "Albert", "Helen", "Joe", "Kingston"),  
 50, replace=T)
 x=as.factor(x)
 plot(x)
```

Comment: This is a very elegant solution, thanks! I wish your answer has been accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `lattice::histogram()`

Comment: A little more explanation will make this answer more useful for the OP and for future users...