# Relative and cumulative percentages for levels of an ordered factor variable in R

Tags: r, frequency, r-factor

The title says it all. I searched over the internet a lot but I was not able to find the answer.

This topic ["Make Frequency Histogram for Factor Variables"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639392/make-frequency-histogram-for-factor-variables) does exactly what I need but for a plot not for a table. I have an ordered factor variable and I need to calculate the relative percentages and the cumulative percentages for each level as if it was a numerical value. I would like to calculate the percentagies and save them in a separate table. 
Any suggestions?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean:

```
X <- sample(LETTERS[1:5],1000,replace=T)
X <- factor(X, ordered=T)
prop.table(table(X))
# X
#     A     B     C     D     E 
# 0.210 0.187 0.180 0.222 0.201

cumsum(prop.table(table(X)))
#     A     B     C     D     E 
# 0.210 0.397 0.577 0.799 1.000
```

This is basically just @Roland's answer from the question you referenced??

**EDIT** (Response to OP's comment)

```
Y <- table(X)
str(Y)
#  'table' int [1:5(1d)] 205 191 200 183 221
#  - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 1
#   ..$ X: chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
Z <- c(table(X))
str(Z)
#  Named int [1:5] 205 191 200 183 221
#  - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "A" "B" "C" "D" ...
```

So `Y` is of class "table", whereas `Z` is a named integer vector. The main difference is the way various R functions treat the different classes. Try `plot(Y)` and `plot(Z)` or `data.frame(Y)` and `data.frame(Z)`. Note, however, that (e.g.) `sum(Y)` and `sum(Z)` return the same thing.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I meant, thank you! Do you know if it would be possible to export the counts/frequencies from the table() in a vector and use them for further calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Try fdth package:

```
library(fdth)
set.seed(2019)
X <- sample(LETTERS[1:5],
            1000,
            replace=T)

X <- factor(X,
            ordered=T)

tb <- fdt_cat(X)
summary(tb)
# Category   f   rf rf(%)   cf cf(%)
#        B 223 0.22  22.3  223  22.3
#        A 210 0.21  21.0  433  43.3
#        C 191 0.19  19.1  624  62.4
#        D 188 0.19  18.8  812  81.2
#        E 188 0.19  18.8 1000 100.0
```