# Histogram of factorial variable including missing values as a level

Tags: r, plot, histogram, missing-data

I have a data frame with a factorial variable that includes missing values. I'd like to plot a histogram including 'a', 'b' and also 'NA' values as another level.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:6, fact1 = factor(c('a','b', 'a', NA, 'a', 'b')))

plot(df1$fact1) # incomplete plot
```

Comment: You mean a barplot, right? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639392/make-frequency-histogram-for-factor-variables. A histogram plots by definition the distribution of a  CONTINUOUS variable (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may just substitute all missing values for a `"NA"` string:

```
dta <- as.character(df1$fact1)
dta[is.na(dta)] <- 'NA'
dta <- as.factor(dta)

barplot(table(dta)) # the same as plot(dta) in this setting
```