# Histogram for frequency of factor variables (EDIT: Now with sample data!)

Tags: r, ggplot2

This problem is similar to, but not the same as, another question with a similar title.

I have a dataframe that includes a factor variable. I want to plot a histogram (preferably in `ggplot2`) that shows integers on the x axis, and a count of factors that have x observations on the y axis. So I could see that x1 factors have 1 observation, x2 factors have 2 observations , etc.

I haven't been able to puzzle through this myself. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: MY QUESTION IS DIFFERENT THAN [Make Frequency Histogram for Factor Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639392/make-frequency-histogram-for-factor-variables).

That question asks, "how many of each factor level are in my dataframe?" That is, how many dogs, how many cats, how many birds.

I am asking, "how many factor levels have x rows?" That is, how many animals have 2 rows? If there are 3 birds and 3 dogs in my dataframe, I want a histogram that shows there are 2 factor levels that have 3 observations.

EDIT2: Hm. I guess I'm not explaining myself well. I've downloaded training data from a Kaggle contest. The data is a set of apartment-for-rent listings. One of the fields in the data is building_id. I've factorized the building_id field. I want to plot: how many buildings have 1 listing in the set? How many buildings have 2 listings in the set? Etc.

Example:

```
listingid  buildingid bedrooms bathrooms etc...
001        001        1        1
002        001        2        1
003        001        1        1
004        001        2        1
005        002        1        1
006        002        2        1
007        002        1        1
008        003        2        2
009        003        1        1
010        004        2        2
011        004        3        1
012        005        1        1
013        006        2        2
014        007        2        1
015        008        1        1
016        009        1        1
```

The plot I want would show:

```
            5| X
 num        4| X
 bldgs.     3| X
            2| X   X
            1| X   X   X   X
             +--------------------------------
num listings:  1   2   3   4
```

The plot shows that one building (building 001) has 4 listings, one building (building 002) has 3 listings, two buildings (003 and 004) have 2 listings, and 5 buildings (005, 006, 007, 008, 009) have one listing.

Comment: without sample data your question is less likely to receive good answer, share first few lines of your dataframe, and also share what have you tried so far

Comment: Also, if you have found another question with a similar title, consider linking to that question. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Frequency Histogram for Factor Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639392/make-frequency-histogram-for-factor-variables)

Comment: Please show a small example and what the expected result is (i.e. what do you consider counting).

Comment: Histograms are for continuous data. You want a bar chart.

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of levels of a factor, we can use `length(levels(myfactor))`. To do this for each factor, we need to know which variables in the data.frame are factors. We perform such check with `which(is.factor(myvariable))`. 
Vectorize these two commands and then do a barplot of them.

```
myfactors <- which(sapply(mydata,is.factor))
factorlengths <- sapply(myfactors,function(i) length(levels(mydata[[i]])))

barplot(factorlengths)
```

In ggplot2 I would do something like the below.

```
mydata2 <- data.frame(x = names(factorlengths), y = factorlengths)

ggplot(mydata2,aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

Is this what you want? If not, please clarify your question [with example data](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

<sub>Purely semantics, but what you want to plot is *not a histogram*.</sub>