# side by side plotting in r for factors with same levels

Tags: r, plot

Data looks like this-

```
ID  Day_start Day_end
1 Sa Sa
2 Sa Tu
3 Sa Tu
3 Sa NA
3 Tu Tr
```

I want to get a side by side bar chart with frequency comparison of different days of Day_start and Day_end.
barplot looks for a vector or matrix but Day_start and Day_end are factors.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make Frequency Histogram for Factor Variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639392/make-frequency-histogram-for-factor-variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want two separate barcharts next to each other you can use `barplot()` & `table()` in base R.

```
my_df <- read.table(text="ID  Day_start Day_end
                           1         Sa      Sa
                           2         Sa      Tu
                           3         Sa      Tu
                           3         Sa      NA
                           3         Tu      Tr", header=T)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
barplot(table(my_df$Day_start))
barplot(table(my_df$Day_end))
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

#### output

[image: side by side base historams]

If you want a grouped barchart you can use `ggplot2` (here I also use `tidyr`'s `gather()` to convert the data to long format).  If you want to show empty space where there's a zero count you can view [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10326729/dont-drop-zero-count-dodged-barplot)

```
library(ggplot2)
long_df <- tidyr::gather(my_df, day_cat, day, -ID)

ggplot(long_df, aes(x=factor(day), fill = day_cat)) + 
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

#### output

[image: ggplot2 grouped bar]

Comment: What is day_cat, day in long_df <- tidyr::gather(my_df, day_cat, day, -ID)?

Comment: i chose day_category to be the name of the output column with the `Day_start`/`Day_end` information (and shortened it).  See the contents of `long_df` and `?tidyr::gather` for some more explanation

Comment: I want the bars not in alphabetic order but in chronological order ....I tried this- data_leftjoin$Day_start = factor(data_leftjoin$Day_start, levels=c("Sa", "Tu", "Tr")) but it not working for me...any suggestion on that?

Comment: the factors take the order of what you pass in the `levels` argument.  so if you want to represent all the days of the week you could pass for example: `levels=c("Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Tr", "Fr", "Sa")` (assuming the day abbreviations are correct)