# How to make frequency barplot in groups?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

Suppose my data is two columns, one is "Condition", one is "Stars"

```
food <- data.frame(Condition = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A"), Stars=c('good','meh','meh','meh','good'))
```

How to make a barplot of the frequency of "Star" as grouped by "Condition"?

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639392/make-frequency-histogram-for-factor-variables) but would like to expand that answer to include groups.

for now I have

```
q <- ggplot(food, aes(x=Stars))
q + geom_bar(aes(y=..count../sum(..count..)))
```

[image]
but that is the proportion of the full data set.

How to make a plot with four bars, that is grouped by 'Condition'?

Eg. 'Condition A' would have 'Good' as 0.66 and 'Meh' as 0.33

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have used value `..prop..`, aesthetic `group` and `facet_wrap()`. Using aesthetic `group` proportions are computed by groups. And `facet_wrap()` is used to plot each condition separately.

```
require(ggplot2)

food <- data.frame(Condition = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A"),
                   Stars=c('good','meh','meh','meh','good'))

ggplot(food) +
  geom_bar(aes(x = Stars, y = ..prop.., group = Condition)) +
  facet_wrap(~ Condition)
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

I guess this is what you are looking for:

```
food <- data.frame(Condition = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A"), Stars=c('good','meh','meh','meh','good'))
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data <- food %>% group_by(Stars,Condition) %>% summarize(n=n()) %>% mutate(freq=n/sum(n)) 

ggplot(data, aes(x=Stars, fill = Condition, group = Condition)) + geom_bar(aes(y=freq), stat="identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image]

At first i have calculated the frequencies using `dplyr` package, which is used as y argument in `geom_bar()`. Then i have used `fill=Condition` argument in `ggplot()` which divided the bars according to Condition. Additionally i have set `position="dodge"` to get the bars next to each other and `stat="identity"`, due to already calculated frequencies.

Comment: thanks, I haven't mentioned it but I prefer the "Star" within "Condition" groups side by side. but still a good solution