# How to group multiple columns together and plot a bar graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, grouping, bar-chart, multiple-columns

I have a data frame that I have split using the `splitstackshape` package. After splitting I unable to proceed with grouping multiple columns and plotting a bar chart. The code is as follows,

```
library(tidyverse)
library(splitstackshape)
df <- data.frame(countries=(c("England","Australia,Pakistan", "India,England","Denmark", "",
                             "Australia, Pakistan, New Zealand, England", "United States, England,Pakistan")))
data_split <- splitstackshape::cSplit(df, "countries", ",")
data_split
```

The output is as follows,

```
countries_1       countries_2 countries_3     countries_4
1:       England        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
2:     Australia    Pakistan        <NA>        <NA>
3:         India     England        <NA>        <NA>
4:       Denmark        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
5:          <NA>        <NA>        <NA>        <NA>
6:     Australia    Pakistan New Zealand     England
7: United States     England    Pakistan        <NA>
```

With the above output I wish to plot a bar chart containing the frequency of countries in descending order. The sample output is as follows,
[bar chart showing frequency of countries in descending order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNU4T.png)

Comment: Maybe it is more straightforward to use `separate_rows` from `tidyr` package (https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_rows.html) and then `ggplot` together with `geom_bar` (https://stackoverflow.com/a/37622400/997979)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  separate_rows(countries, sep = ",") %>% 
  count(countries) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = fct_reorder(countries, n), x = n)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

---

Edit based on comment: plot only 10 most common countries:

```
df %>% 
  separate_rows(countries, sep = ",") %>% 
  count(countries) %>% 
  slice_max(n, n = 10) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(y = fct_reorder(countries, n), x = n)) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: Got it Sir. But the actual data set I am working on has 120 odd countries. So, when I run the output the entire chart is completely overlapped. I wish to show only top 10 countries because the frequency of countries after the first 10 is very less. How can I incorporate that step into the code ?

Comment: Add this line `slice_max(n, n = 10) %>% ` the line with `count` (see updated answer)

Comment: Thank you so for answering my first question. Means a lot.

Comment: You're welcome! Consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark next to it if it answered you question.