# Does it possible to make histogram in R but the x axis value is in decimal. and pre-determined manually

Tags: r, statistics

I want to make a histogram where there are range with decimal on the x axis, does it possible?

```
        data=c(321.68 , 329.51 , 327.89 , 291.97 , 303.26 , 297.18 , 466.74, 
    251.75 , 327.12 , 283.10 , 282.87 , 244.96 , 296.46 , 264.03 ,
 388.35 , 220.89 , 244.98 , 254.59 , 322.18 , 319.80 , 356.25 , 310.51 , 
299.82 , 314.21 , 303.92 , 303.43 , 293.38 , 311.32 , 269.70 , 261.95 , 247.82 , 202.95 , 278.73 , 260.34 , 262.73 , 281.83)
```

for example the first range start at 202.95 until 246.915

I tried using the breaks command but it just makes more abstract

Comment: The `breaks` argument is the correct one.  How did you use it?  It should be something like `breaks = c(202.95, 246.915, ... )`

Comment: it works, but is there a way to change the parameter of the x axis to the range, instead of 200,250,300, and so on?

Answer (score 1):

I believe, that what you are going for is to group you vector into intervals and count the number in each interval.

I think your question is similar to what was asked [in this other thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639392/make-frequency-histogram-for-factor-variables).

The solution to your question would then be along these lines:

```r
data=c(321.68 , 329.51 , 327.89 , 291.97 , 303.26 , 297.18 , 466.74 , 251.75 , 327.12 , 283.10 , 282.87 , 244.96 , 296.46 , 264.03 , 388.35 , 220.89 , 244.98 , 254.59 , 322.18 , 319.80 , 356.25 , 310.51 , 299.82 , 314.21 , 303.92 , 303.43 , 293.38 , 311.32 , 269.70 , 261.95 , 247.82 , 202.95 , 278.73 , 260.34 , 262.73 , 281.83)

barplot(prop.table(table(cut(
  data,
  c(202.95, 246.915, 282.87, 303.26, 466.74 ),
  include.lowest = TRUE
))))
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>